# How to replace ']' with a new string when the text is stored in variable?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

My MWE is here

```
#!/bin/bash
num=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings | grep -oE '[0-9]+'|sort -rn|head -n 1)
num=$((num + 1))
echo $num
#gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "[<altered_list>]"
#gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "[$key , $key $num]"
key="/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom"
list=$(gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings)
newnum=$(echo "${list}" | grep -oE '[0-9]+' |sort -rn|head -n 1)
echo $newnum
sed -e "/]/${key}${newnum}/" ${list}
#gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "[$key , $key $num]"
echo $key
```

I want to `sed -e "/]/${key}${newnum}/" ${list}` that means from -

```
['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']
```

I want to get

```
['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/','/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/']
```

add a extra `custom3` in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]]` to represent the `]` in a regex.  Use `@` as the sed expression delimiter since your replacement string has `/` in it.

```
sed -e "s@[]]@${key}${newnum}@" ${list}
```

You can also escape it with a backslash:

```
sed -e "s@\]@${key}${newnum}@" ${list}
```

Since `]` is known to be at the end of the string, you could also change the last character without regard to what it is:

```
sed -e "s@.\$@${key}${newnum}@" ${list}
```

Comment: `sed -e "/\]/${key}${newnum}/" ${list}` results `sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `/'`. This error occurs for all 3 expression.

Comment: You have `/` in your replacement string that messes up with the `sed` expression.  See the updated answer.

Comment: same error `sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: @'`

Comment: My bad, `s` was missing in the beginning.  Please see the update.

Comment: Also note that this `sed` command assumes that `$list` is a file while the OP's code seems to want to work on `$list` itself (as a string) for whatever reason.

Comment: @codeforester `sed: -e expression #1, char 76: unterminated `s' command
`